# Jenkins Not to Starting After Update

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-multibranch

I have a Jenkins instance (running on Ubuntu 16.04.3) that I've kept more or less up to date over the last couple of years. Today I tried updating via aptitude (`apt-get dist-upgrade`) only to get this exception:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.GithubSecurityRealm
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at hudson.util.XStream2$CompatibilityMapper.realClass(XStream2.java:285)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at hudson.util.xstream.MapperDelegate.realClass(MapperDelegate.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:48)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.determineType(RobustReflectionConverter.java:461)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:327)
Caused: jenkins.util.xstream.CriticalXStreamException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.GithubSecurityRealm : org.jenkinsci.plugins.GithubSecurityRealm
---- Debugging information ----
message             : org.jenkinsci.plugins.GithubSecurityRealm
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : org.jenkinsci.plugins.GithubSecurityRealm
class               : hudson.model.Hudson
required-type       : hudson.model.Hudson
converter-type      : hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter
path                : /hudson/securityRealm
line number         : 85
version             : not available
-------------------------------
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:356)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.unmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:270)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1189)
    at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:114)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1173)
    at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:165)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /mnt/tank/jenkins/home/config.xml
    at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:167)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.loadConfig(Jenkins.java:3031)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.access$1200(Jenkins.java:304)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$14.run(Jenkins.java:3049)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1068)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:269)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:48)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1102)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:904)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:86)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:233)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:250)
```

I'm now on 2.96. I'm not sure what version I was on before.

I saw this post regarding [Jenkins restart error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47227625/jenkins-restart-error-org-jenkinsci-plugins-githubauthorizationstrategy) but in my case this file doesn't exist (`find ~/ -name github-oauth.jpi.disabled` comes up empty).

I tried `for p in $HOME/plugins/*.jpi; do touch $p.disabled; done`. When I do that, the server complains about missing the matrix auth plugin. Re-enabling that single plugin causes the error to display again.

Comment: ```Unable to read /mnt/tank/jenkins/home/config.xml``` do you have this file?

Comment: Yes, this file did actually exist on my system, and Jenkins could read it

Answer (score 1):

The answer was:

1. Open `~/config.xml` and change the `class` attribute of the `securityRealm` tag from `org.jenkinsci.plugins.GithubSecurityRealm` to `hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm` as indicated [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-oauth-plugin#troubleshooting-installation)

   - In my case, I had a user for myself in the database, but you may need to do something more drastic like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988849/how-to-reset-jenkins-security-settings-from-the-command-line)
2. Restart Jenkins
3. Update all plugins
4. Adjust security settings in Jenkins admin
5. (Repeat, if required)

There may be an incompatibility with the Github Auth plugin and the newest auth matrix. I've switched us from auth matrix to per-repository authentication so I have not explored this potential issue further.